# Can one Observable have multiple subscribers?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have one Observable and I thought that one Observable can have only one subscriber. But the code below subscribes twice and works fine for two subscribers - how come? (What I mean is both `received0` and `received1` are printed)

```
const observable = new Observable((subscriber) => {
      sub : Subscriber;
      
      setTimeout(() => {
        subscriber.next(4);
        subscriber.complete();
      }, 2000);
    });
    observable.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        console.log("received0: "+value);
      }
    });
    observable.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        console.log("received1: "+value);
      }
    });
```

Comment: The above code is absolutely right

Comment: it's absolutely obvious from the table at the top of the [observable documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)

Comment: Why not? It'd be really limiting to have only 1 subscriber. Do note though that each subscriber creates a new instance of the observable, as in the callback will be called again. If you put a log before the setTimeout you'll see it displayed as many times as you've got subscribers. If what you want is to share a subscription and no matter how many times you subscribe to it, the parent is only created once, then look into shareReplay or share

Comment: Does subscribe create new instance of observable?. So what is `new Observable` syntax for? I would think that creates new instance of `Observable`

Comment: The `subscribe` method does not create a new instance of `Observable`. You already have create an instance of `Observable` in this line: `const observable = new Observable(...)`, The `subscribe()` only registers the new subscriber (or callback you can say) to be executed on the next emit.

Comment: I am completely confused. 
maxime1992 says it does then  BadPiggie says it doesn't. So what is it? Does subscribe create new instance of Observable or it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Observable can have multiple subscribers.

It won't create multiple `Observable` but it will create multiple `Subscription` which will execute the same Observable multiple times.
https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription

BTW, If you don't want to execute the same Observable multiple times you can use `share` to avoid that.
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share

Comment: I thought that this is the main difference between Observable and Subject. Subject can have multiple subscribers. Am I confusing something here. Is subscriber the same as implementation of the observer?

Comment: You may be confused about the multicast.  A`Subject` is multicast means if there are multiple `Subscription` it would only execute once and other`Observable` is unicast.  You still can subscribe to it multiple times but it will execute multiple times. And yes, a `Subscription` is the execution of an Observable. BTW, a `Subject` is also an `Observable`.

Comment: Observable is created always with Observer - there is no other construct for Observable but just `new Observable (function (obs : any) {}` - so doesn't it mean that Observable can have only one Observer?

Comment: Observable is NOT created with Observer. Observer uses with Subscription. Many APIs can create Observable such as `of`.  There is no such limit.

Comment: Sorry Observable is created by default with one Subscriber (which is also an Observer) right?

Comment: Observable is the one created by Observable construct or other Apis. A `Subscription` will be created by subscribing to an `Observable` with an `Observer` (the prop `{next:...}` of `.subscribe()`).